# Cocoa application not responding to 'activate' applescript event

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript

I am developing a Cocoa application using Xamarin.Mac.  The application compiles and runs well, however, when I attempt to launch it via AppleScript, the launch always fails due to a timeout error.  (The application itself is quite small.  It typically launches in less than 2 or 3 seconds)

- If I double-click /Applications/MyApp.app using the Finder, the application launches fine.
- If I type $open /Applications/MyApp.app in a bash shell, the application launches fine.
- When I type $osascript -e 'tell application "MyApp" to activate', the application does not appear to launch, and I get a result of "45:53: execution error: MyApp got an error: AppleEvent timed out. (-1712)"
- When MyApp.app is running, I can issue the command $osascript -e 'tell application "MyApp" to quit', and the application quits as expected.
- When I type $osascript -e 'tell application "Dictionary" to activate', the Dictionary application (in /Applications) launches.

--
I'm assuming that there is something wrong with my application that is preventing it from responding to the 'activate' event when it is not running.  However, I don't know where to go to debug it.  (There are no entries in the console log indicating a problem, and a logging event in the "Main" function doesn't log anything, making me believe that my application isn't being launched)

Any ideas on where I can look to figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark: try using the keyword `launch` instead of activate.

Comment: I follow up by adding that you should tell application "YourApp" to set frontmost to true. (This is a novelty in Yosemite.)

Comment: No, `activate` is a standard event that works out of the box in all Carbon/Cocoa apps, and users will expect it to work. Sounds like the app is being launched (AppleScript calls `LSLaunchApplication` if needed before sending an Apple event), but is hanging before its event loop is fully up and running. Could be an problem in Xamarin itself: cross-platform application frameworks (which tend to implement their own event loops) might not replicate Mac-specific behaviors like default AE handling quite right. OP might be best asking the vendor or other Xamarin.Mac users for advice.

Comment: Actually, at least if you do UI Scripting, then `set frontmost to true` is required (under Yosemite), if you for instance are scripting Safari, so I recommended that as a 'backdoor' to make it activate, but maybe it even won't respond to that when it doesn't respond to **activate**. Maybe something other that *can* work, is to `tell application "System Events to set frontmost of application process "YourApp" to true`.

Comment: The OP is trying to fix a bug in his own application. Telling him to tell his users to use workarounds isn't really a solution.

Comment: Well, then  I should really have told him to read the **technical note** titled **Debugging Magic**.